# Rename all files in directory

Tags: linux, file-rename

I'm trying to rename the files like:
**Name1_searchstats_metrics_20141230T133000036.log**
to something like: **Name2_searchstats_metrics_20141230T133000036.log**

I'm trying: `rename -n 's/\Name1_/\Name2_/' *.log` but am getting the error:

```
bash: /usr/bin/rename: Argument list too long
```

Can someone please help ?

Comment: This is because you have so many files expanded with the `*.log` pattern. Maybe you can use `find` or a `while` loop

Answer (score 6, accepted):

probably the easiest solution, since you're using bash is to iterate over the list of files with a `for` loop:

```
$ for i in *; do rename -n 's/Name1_/Name2_/' $i; done
```

you can also filter the files if needed by using any wildcard in the command, like `*.log`.

There are other more convoluted ways to achieve this, especially if you need to do particular string manipulation of the file name, i.e. using `awk` or `find -exec`, but hopefully this could help you sort things out in a clear way.

Edited answer as suggested by @glglgl

a more comprehensive and detailed explanation of the above can be found on superuser:
https://superuser.com/questions/31464/looping-through-ls-results-in-bash-shell-script

Comment: `for i in *.log` has not these restrictions, and using `\`ls`\` is always error-prone and should be avoided.

Comment: thanks, edited my answer to be more clear.

Answer (score 2):

If the argument list is too long for a linux command, [`xargs`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xargs) usually comes to the rescue.

Try this:

```
ls *.log | xargs rename -n 's/\Name1_/\Name2_/'
```

Comment: I don't have access to a UNIX terminal here at work, so not sure if I got the syntax right, but I guess it should work.

Comment: Getting the same error with this command also

Comment: In your original command (that you posted in the question), try by first feeding it less number of files (say 10 or so). See if that succeeds.

Comment: @SaurabhVerma How many log files are you passing to the rename command? If it is several million, it is possible that the sublists created by xargs are *also* too big. Disclaimer: I don't know how xargs splits its input into sublists, that is, how big is each sublist, and what is the "threshold" for rename to consider its input list as too big.